# I get confirmation of my posted open graph action, but don't see any posts

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I am using the new Facebook IOS SDK 3.0 and have integrated the Scrumptious sample into my app. I have specified the namespace and action for my app correctly. When I click "announce", I get "posted open graph action, id: xxxxx" so it looks like my post is successful. I am assuming the post will go to my personal Facebook news stream since that I who I am logged in as, however I don't see anything. Is there anything that needs to be done with my app to make it active? Or other settings that I might be overlooking? Thanks.

Comment: I am trying with prior to facebook 3 sdk version, I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I didn't enable timeline on my facebook account so I didn't see the posts. Once I enabled it, I was able to see them. I could also see them in my activity log. I have another issue with tags now, but at least I am able to post now. Thanks.